# If/else not catching inside method on button press

Tags: android, if-statement

So I've got a method that runs on a button press and everything comes up perfect except where I have a bit of an internal if/else if/else loop. I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing but I just can't seem to see it.

In the code below I've got it finding the hourtype but even when I set it to false directly the if/else doesn't trigger. It's able to get the hour int just fine but it won't subtract 12 from it like it's supposed to.

I know I don't have the date type specified here because I did that already earlier on. That's not the issue here. Like I said, I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing because I've been staring at it too long. Here's the method:

```
public String enterMood(View v) {
    try {
        int month = dPick.getMonth();
        int day = dPick.getDayOfMonth();
        int year = dPick.getYear();
        int minute = tPick.getCurrentMinute();
        String moodAntePost = "AM";
        hourType = tPick.is24HourView();
        moodHour = tPick.getCurrentHour();
        if (hourType = false) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                                // can't fathom.
            if (moodHour > 12) {
                moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
                moodAntePost = "PM";
            }
        } else if (hourType = false) {
            if (moodHour <= 0) {
                moodHour = 12;
            }
        } else {
        }
        String noteText = noteField.getText().toString();
        Mood = "Happiness," + happyValue + ",Energy," + energyValue
                + ",Anxiety," + anxietyValue + ",Pain," + painValue
                + ",Date," + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ",Time,"
                + moodHour + ":" + minute + "," + moodAntePost + ",Note,"
                + noteText;
        System.out.println(Mood); //Just to print to the LogCat
    } catch (Exception buttonListenerException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", buttonListenerException);
    }
    return Mood;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `hourType = false` should be `hourType == false` or, even better `!hourType`

Comment: Thank you much. That was the problem. I feel like an idiot now. *grins*

Answer (score 4):

Clarification: `=` is used for assigning purpose e.g. `int x = 10;` whereas `==` is used for comparison e.g. `boolean isX10 = x==10;`

your `if` statement is wrong do this:

```
 if (hourType == false) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                            // can't fathom.
```

**OR**

```
 if (!hourType) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                            // can't fathom.
```

instead of

```
 if (hourType = false) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                            // can't fathom.
```

Comment: Correct. `=` means to assign, `==` to compared. You should include this in your answer for the OP.

Comment: sure, I should add this too :)

Answer (score 0):

if and else if both are checking same condition in wrong syntax it should be something like

```
 if (hourType == false) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                                    // can't fathom.
                if (moodHour > 12) {
                    moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
                    moodAntePost = "PM";
                }
            } else if (hourType == true) {
                if (moodHour <= 0) {
                    moodHour = 12;
                }
```

or

```
 if (!hourType) { // Not hitting this point for some reason I
                                        // can't fathom.
                    if (moodHour > 12) {
                        moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
                        moodAntePost = "PM";
                    }
                } else if (hourType) {
                    if (moodHour <= 0) {
                        moodHour = 12;
                    }
```